# Apostrophe use in singular (and parenthesized plural) possessive noun(s)

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, writing-style, apostrophe, parenthetical-plural

How would one combine the sigular and plural possessive forms of *contractor* into one form? Like for example *contractor’(s’)*.

A friend of mine is busy editing a fairly technical document and arrived at an interesting dilemma. We were confused over how to use the *’s*  possessive in a sentence regarding contractor liability.

The sentence had to cover not only the singular *contractor* and the plural *contractors*, but also the possessive form, like  *contractor’s* and *contractors’* both.

How do you do that?  Or would one rather use the plural and imply that the singular in included in the meaning?

Comment: It's *contractor(s)'* -- naturally. The apostrophe comes much later, the noun in its complete form comes first. On a different note: I'd use the *of* form rather than the apostrophe-s alternative for the possessive here; why make things so complex?

Comment: Kris i showed the answers to my friend and she immediately realised the "of" form was the way to go. I personally would have gone with Kim's singular entity form, but then again I'm not an editor (nor is English my first language).  Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I recall that many legal cotracts start with a definition of terms such as _The cotractror refers to Mr A, Ms B etc_, so it's defining the single entity up front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would intepret contractor to be a person, or persons, or a company of people. So you can treat it as a singular entity, and *contactor's* is the only possisve form of abbreviation. There must be many legal documents that would confirm this usage.